# External HDD not always detected

Tags: mount, hard-drive

It is detected perfectly fine on my Mac.

It is self-powered an I hear it spin when I plug it in the Pi.

Sometimes when I boot it shows when I run `lsusb`, sometimes it doesn't. If I unplug it and try plugging it in a different port, it is eventually detected after a few tries. (And then I can mount it with ntfs-3g and it works fine, although I haven't managed auto-mounting for the few times it was detected at boot)

I think it cannot be a driver problem because it is detected sometimes. Can't be power either since it has its own PSU. I'm really at a loss. Not a defective USB port either, I've managed to get it mounted at least once from each port.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should have a look in `/var/log/kern.log` (on raspbian) or at `dmesg` after you plug it in to see if the kernel does anything at all.  There doesn't even need to be a specific driver for something to show up in `lsusb` (i.e., you could have a USB device with no driver at all, it should still be detected and shown there) -- so this is strange.

Comment: The drive was already ntfs, or did you just partition and  format?

Comment: Looked up dmesg, nothing there that seems related to the drive either (only USB related things seem to be about the buses themselves or my wifi dongle, no mention of "Seagate" or "storage" or anything of the sort). I've partitioned the drive a few times, it currently has an HFS+ partition (two actually, including the ~20MB one that's created automatically) and an NTFS one. Both work properly on my Mac (the HFS+ one natively, the NTFS one through my Windows virtual machine).

Comment: Is it possible the drive is the cause? USB communication is out of my scope of knowledge, but something I could think of is the drive not identifying itself properly when connected, preventing the Pi from detecting it (whereas my Mac could be somehow more tolerant, or have routines to try stuff until it's detected...?)